# Inserting into scrapy items

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy

So, I think I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around python Dicts. I have a **scraper** , where I successfully managed to make a dictionary parsing through webpages; now its time to insert into items I have defined as **scrapy Field**

```
class ApplicationItem(Item):
 Case_reference = Field()
 Application_name = Field()
 Contact_name = Field()
 Contact_telephone = Field()
```

where I create a python Dictionary like this:

```
{u" Applicant's name: ": u' KIMARO COMPANY INC ',
 u' Case reference: ': u' ARB/15/00696 ',
 u' Contact name: ': u' ',
 u' Contact telephone: ': u' 07957 140179 ' }
```

my question is how would I make sure that I am inserting the correct value from the dictionary to scrapy item.
I have this so far:

```
for res, rec in application.items():
    item['Case_reference'] = application.get(result(res))
    item['Application_name'] = application.get(result(res))
    item['Contact_name'] = application.get(result(res))
    item['Contact_telephone'] = application.get(result(res))
```

which I don not think would do what I expect! I am actually getting python typeError on this.
Any Idea?

**item** is an actual field that I am trying to insert. So it is an instance of **ApplicationItem**

```
item['Case_reference'] = application.get()
```

is the way I try to insert from a previously created dict into each field.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `item[res] = application.get(result(res))` (and only that one line in the loop)?

Comment: what rec is used for in the loop ?

Comment: Is `item` an instance of `ApplicationItem`? You are not giving enough information, since I read your code, and I don't know what is what! If `item` is an instance of `ApplicationItem`, then it's not supposed to be `item['Application's name']` or something like that

Comment: @btquanto good procedure is here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html  so item[res] is not correct. In any case it seems code is missing so not possible to give advices

Comment: Also, is `application` the  dictionary you provided? What is `result`? You are getting `TypeError`, and you're not even giving information about your object's types, or the stack trace.

Comment: @aberna Yeah, I wasn't sure, since I didn't know what `item` was, as stated in my other comments

Comment: @btquanto That's not working since res is not an instance of ApplicationItem Field.

Comment: @aberna Sure. Should be something like `setattr(item, 'Application_name', value)`. To make it dynamic, he's going to need a dictionary to map `"Application's name"` with `"Application_name"`

Comment: @btquanto Yes, That's right; I need to make sure the item field that I am inserting into has the same attribute as in the dictionary created before.

Answer (score 0):

Since `item` is not a dictionary, you cannot call `item['key'] = value`.

Instead, use:

```
setattr(obj, attribute, value)
```

Try this code:

```
class ApplicationItem(Item):
    ATTRIBUTE_MAPPINGS = {
        " Applicant's name: " : "Application_name",
        " Case refference " : "Case_reference",
        " Contact name: " : "Contact_name",
        "' Contact telephone: " : "Contact_telephone",
    }
    Case_reference = Field()
    Application_name = Field()
    Contact_name = Field()
    Contact_telephone = Field()
```

And your loop would be:

```
for key, value in application.iteritems():
    setattr(item, ApplicationItem.ATTRIBUTE_MAPPINGS[key], application.get(result(key)))
```